# raphael text manipulation using text area as entry

Tags: javascript, textarea, raphael

I am trying to use a text area to gather input from the user and then when the user clicks a done button. I grab the textarea value and insert it into Raphael text object. Easy enough. However, I realized after typing out a paragraph in the text area that a number of things occur. Here are a couple of things that occur.

1. Although in the text area it looks like its on multiple lines it actually just puts it all on one line. (Makes sense after thinking about it for two seconds)
2. When I hit enter it puts the text onto a new line but if I hit enter and add mulitples new lines above the text it just ignores them.

So basically what I am asking is does anyone know the best way or any way that is more consistent and efficient to take textarea text and formatting it properly to look the same way in Raphael. Tips tricks would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, 22%?  That's impressively low.  I would suggest breaking the input text into words and using `print` instead of `text` -- that way you can wrap words programmatically, although the task of replicating the word breaks in the textarea is no small task.

Comment: And this really has nothing to do with Raphael, but only with the textarea behaviour. Do some reading on textarea attributes and how they work in different browsers.